# Dynamic buckets based on slicer

Tags: powerbi

I have this table

```
usr box app device  bucket      bucket_box  bucket_app  bucket_box_app  month
u1  b1  a1  d1      > 3         3 devices   2 devices   2 devices       201809
u1  b1  a1  d2      > 3         3 devices   2 devices   2 devices       201809
u1  b1  a2  d3      > 3         3 devices   2 devices   1 device        201809
u1  b2  a2  d4      > 3         1 device    2 devices   1 device        201809
u2  b1  a1  d5      > 3         1 device    2 devices   1 device        201809
u2  b2  a3  d6      > 3         2 devices   1 device    1 device        201809
u2  b2  a4  d7      > 3         2 devices   1 device    1 device        201809
u2  b3  a1  d8      > 3         1 device    2 devices   1 device        201809
u3  b3  a1  d9      3 devices   2 devices   2 devices   1 device        201809
u3  b4  a1  d10     3 devices   1 device    1 device    1 device        201809
u3  b3  a2  d11     3 devices   2 devices   2 devices   1 device        201809
```

I've created 2 slicers on column **box** and **app**.
In a Clustered column chart, on values I have count distinct usr.
On legend I want to calculate a breakdown on usr by device. The buckets are 1 device, 2 devices, 3 devices, more that 3 devices.

#### if no selections in slicers:

- count distinct usr = 3
- 2 usr -> more that 3 devices
- 1 usr -> 3 devices

#### if b1 is used as filter:

- count distinct usr = 2
- 1 usr -> 3 devices
- 1 usr -> 1 device

#### if a1 is used as filter:

- count distinct usr = 3
- 3 usr -> 2 devices

#### if a1 and b1 are used as filters:

- count distinct usr = 2
- 1 usr -> 2 devices
- 1 usr -> 1 device

How can I do this?

**LATER EDIT**

I've changed the source table a little bit to be exactly as I have it now.
You can download the report from [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AglE3pyiOyn2ixpIYHpGKkZg_hT5)
I want a dynamic count group by. Every time a slicer is filtered, there should be a count(device) group by usr, then based on this count the buckets are made: how many users on current filters have 1 device, 2 devices, 3 devices or more than 3 devices. On axis I've put month column, but it is irrelevant for this example because it has only one value.

Comment: I'm having trouble visualizing what you want your chart to look like. Can you do a mockup of the first or second case you describe?

Comment: I've changed the original post a little bit. You can find there also the report source.

Comment: This question is very similar in nature to one I answered a couple days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52169206/dax-grouping-by-a-measure-result/52170566

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned above, this question is essentially a duplicate of:
[DAX grouping by a measure result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52169206/dax-grouping-by-a-measure-result/)

You need to create a new table `Buckets` for your categories:

```
Bucket
------
1 device
2 devices
3 devices
>3 devices
```

Once you have that, put it in the Legend box and use the following measure for the Value box:

```
DynamicBucketingMeasure =
    VAR Summary =
        SUMMARIZE (
            ALLSELECTED ( pbi_box_active_devices_4 ),
            pbi_box_active_devices_4[usr],
            "Devices", DISTINCTCOUNT ( pbi_box_active_devices_4[device] )
        )
    VAR Bucketed =
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            Summary,
            "Bucket", SWITCH (
                TRUE (),
                [Devices] > 3, ">3 devices",
                [Devices] = 1, "1 device",
                [Devices] & " devices"
            )
        )
    RETURN
        SUMX ( Bucketed, IF ( [Bucket] = SELECTEDVALUE ( Buckets[Bucket] ), 1, 0 ) )
```

Note that in this measure, I've split the counting and subsequent bucketing into two steps rather than combining them into one like I did in the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

Super! It works fine when I'm not using month on Axis. On a larger dataset, with data on more months, on all axis values it did a sum of all data. So, all the bucket groups have the same data. I've tried to add month column to group by like this:

```
VAR Summary =
    SUMMARIZE (
        ALLSELECTED ( pbi_box_active_devices_4 ),
        pbi_box_active_devices_4[usr],
        pbi_box_active_devices_4[month],
        "Devices", DISTINCTCOUNT ( pbi_box_active_devices_4[device] )
    )
```

but it is not working as expected.